# How to delay the evaluation of function arguments in R?

Tags: r, rlang

I would like to delay the evaluation of a function argument in R. Example:

```r
my_func <- function(FUN){print(FUN); print(FUN)}
my_func(runif(1))
#> [1] 0.2833882
#> [1] 0.2833882
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

This works as documented because `runif(1)` is only evaluated once and its results printed twice.

Instead, I don't want `runif(1)` to be evaluated until it is within each print() statement. This would generate two different random numbers.

In other words, I don't want FUN to "resolve" --- if that is the right word --- to `runif(1)` until we are within a `print()` statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can also achieve this with `substitute` and `eval`:

```r
my_func <- function(FUN) {
  print(eval(substitute(FUN)))
  print(eval(substitute(FUN)))
}

my_func(runif(1))
#> [1] 0.09973534
#> [1] 0.8096205

my_func(runif(1))
#> [1] 0.2231202
#> [1] 0.5386637
```

NB: For additional details, check out this chapter [Non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) of Advanced R

Answer (score 2):

Here is one trick with `match.call` and `eval`

```
my_func <- function(FUN){
  print(eval(match.call()[[2]])) 
  print(eval(match.call()[[2]]))
}

my_func(runif(1))

#[1] 0.7439711
#[1] 0.5011816

my_func(runif(1))
#[1] 0.7864152
#[1] 0.730453
```

Answer (score 0):

provide and expression

```
f = function(EXPR){
  print(EXPR)
  eval(EXPR)
}

EXPR = expression(runif(1))
> f(EXPR)
expression(runif(1))
[1] 0.1761139
```

provide an string

```
f2 = function(STR){
  print(STR)
  eval(parse(text = STR)) 
}

STR = "runif(1)"
> f2(STR)
[1] "runif(1)"
[1] 0.7630865
```